# Cleaning a food processor

Tags: cleaning

A family member of mine passed away many years ago (15-16 years) and had a lot of cooking gadgets.  Well, recently I've been becoming more interested in cooking and have acquired a few of these tools.  This weekend I found a food processor in the box wrapped up.  I asked my parents about it and they said that after this family member passed away and the stuff was boxed up it was put away in storage (where I got it this weekend).

Anyway, this thing hasn't been used since the family member passed away.  Is it going to be OK to use?  Is there anything special I need to do to clean it and get it operational?  It looks like it's clean but sitting around that long, you never know, right?

Answer (score 6):

If it looks clean and it's been sitting in a box I would just run it through my regular washing routine.  Unless it was stored dirty or with some hazardous materials there is no reason to do anything more.

Answer (score 4):

On a usage note, I've found that they are much easier to clean if you do so immediately after use than if you wait until later.

Answer (score 2):

After 15 years of non use cleaning is not your problem. Depending on what model it is the gears, bearings and bushings will be packed with grease (often silicone based) and these will have most likely dried out to some degree

Using it without checking these could cause mechanical failure

Pull the covers off and have a look. Often the grease is OK, but has retracted from the gear surface, just re-spread it around. If not confident with doing this send it to a service centre